# How to list (and count) all the models in a DBT project?

Tags: command-line-interface, dbt

I'd like to list and count all the DBT models (every single `.sql` table) within my DBT project.

I see the `dbt ls` https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/commands/list
but I'm new and can't make it work in order to list all the models.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `dbt ls --select snowplow.*` change `snowplow` to whatever you named your table/models

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dbt ls` on its own will list all nodes which include tests, snapshots, seeds, etc. To list just the models you can run `dbt ls --resource-type model`. However, you don't want to pipe that directly into `wc` because dbt prints out logging info by default. To get around that you can add `-q` to the `dbt` command.

```
dbt -q ls --resource-type model | wc -l
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried

```
dbt ls --select my_project
```

where `my_project` should be defined in the `dbt_project.yml` by the variable `name:` . This returns

```
my_project.my_folder.my_schema1.model1
my_project.my_folder.my_schema1.model2
[...]
my_project.my_folder.my_schema2.model1
[...]
```

So

```
dbt ls --select my_project | wc -l
```

gave me the number of models in `my_project`.

In case is needed to skip some WARNING (or anything else) records adding an `egrep -v` should help:

```
dbt ls --select my_project | egrep -v 'WARNING' | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this directly solves your issue but:

```
dbt docs generate
```

Does print out the number of models found.